# 550 error vsftpd

Tags: debian, ftp, vsftpd

550 permission denied vsftpd 
Поднимаю ftp сервер на Debian 9. При попытке создать директорию\файл выскакивает ошибка. Необходимо дать разрешение единственному пользователю (ftpuser) полный доступ к шаре. Что я делаю не так? 
 Спасибо. 
 [image: Здесь конфиг - /etc/vsftpd.conf.] 
 [image: Сообщение об ошибке на стороне клиента.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге работает. Просто использовал userlist и убрал полностью всё про guest.

Answer (score 0):

Частая ошибка, для начала убедитесь в наличии строки `write_enable=YES` в конфиге сервера .
Если после этого, ничего не поменялось, то проверьте права у папки на сервере, ftp пользователь должен иметь права на запись в них. Для установки прав на папку воспользуйтесь командой:
`sudo chmod -R ftpuser:ftpuser /path/to/folder`

Comment: Сделал владельцем папки ftpuser, дал полные права. write_enable=YES установлено (см. скрины). Всё ещё не работает.

Comment: Попробуйте поменять local_umask на 022

Comment: Всё равно не работает :(

Comment: Я в ступоре, вроде всё должно работать. Тут мои полномочия - всё.

Comment: Единственный вариант - ftpuser воспринимается как гость без прав.